# How to use AJAX Request with Vanilla JS and process the return request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this JavaScript method that aims to get a request from a database and I really have no basic background in JavaScript. My method looks like:

```
(function () {
    function contentLoaded () {    
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                if(document.getElementById('isbn')){
                    var item = document.getElementById('isbn').value;
                    if(item !== ''){
                        if(window.location.href.includes('/account/create')){
                            var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            httpRequest.open('GET', "http://"+window.location.hostname+":"+window.location.port+"/book/search/"+item);
                            console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, false);
    }
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', contentLoaded, false); 
}());
```

If I manually entered my request on the browser, it gives me a data of type JSON which oppose to my log console that gives me an empty. How can i get my request within my method and then process it?

Comment: `httpRequest.addEventListener('load', function() {console.log(this.responseText)})`

Comment: and you are missing `httpRequest.send();` see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Use `Fetch API - Web APIs`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Instead of all the `XMLHttpRequest` commands, use `fetch("/book/search/ + item).then(res => res.text()).then(res => console.log(res));`